# Allen-Cahn heteroclinic

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the scalar Allen-Cahn equation
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+u-u^3.
$$
The spatially homogeneous equilibria are $u=0,\pm1$.

$u=0$ is unstable, $u=\pm1$ are stable.

Looking at the phase plane one sees that there are heteroclinic Orbits connecting -1 and +1.

1) What type of equilibria are $u=\pm1$?

Linearization in $u=\pm1$ shows that both equilibria are Center since the linearization matrix has eigenvalues $\pm\sqrt{2}i$ if I am not mistaken.

2) How can there be a heteroclinic Orbit between to centers?

Comment: What "phase plane" do you look at? Is it the phase plane of the ODE $u_t=u-u^3$?

Comment: Phase plane of the System $u_x=v, v_x=-u+u^3$

Comment: So the PDE plays no role here, you are only considering constant in time solutions.

Comment: Yes. It’s the traveling wave ODE $-cU‘=U‘‘+U-U^3$ with $U(\xi)=U(x-ct)$ with c=0.

Comment: http://math.arizona.edu/~lega/583/Fall98/lectnotes/PDE3.html up to this (page 3), the connections are between -1 and 1.

Comment: I am reading these notes myself. They are interesting but I am having the same doubts as you. I think that the notes have been hastily written and that they are misleading. In particular, the trajectories connecting $-1$ and $1$ should not be there. Moreover, he does not really explain how he drew these lines.

Comment: I think I realized that the trajectory connecting $-1$ and $-1$ is an asymptotic one. It corresponds to the unique solution to $u''+u=u^3, u(0)=0, u'(0)=\sqrt{2}/2$, which is a function such that $\lim_{t\to \pm \infty} (u(t), u'(t))=(\pm 1, 0)$. So these trajectories do NOT connect $-1$ and $+1$, even if they look like they do, but they do it in an INFINITE time.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a sign mistake. As noted in comments, the dynamical system is 
$$
\begin{cases} 
u_x = v , \\ 
v_x = u^3 - u,
\end{cases}
$$ 
so its linearization around the equilibria $(u, v)=(\pm 1, 0 )$ is 
$$
\begin{cases} 
u_x = v, \\ 
v_x = 2 u,
\end{cases}$$ 
corresponding to the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\  2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, whose eigenvalues are $\pm \sqrt 2$. So the equilibria are not centers.

**EDIT** Answer to 2. You say that [the phase plane](http://math.arizona.edu/~lega/583/Fall98/lectnotes/PDE3.html) (pag. 3) shows two heteroclinic connecting the stationary solutions $-1$, $+1$. This is not in contradiction because the trajectories correspond to solutions $u_{\pm}$ such that 
$$\lim_{t\to \pm \infty} (u_{\pm}(t), u'_{\pm}(t))=(\pm 1, 0).$$ 
So the trajectories do not really "connect" the two stationary solutions, because they do so in infinite time.

Comment: I think the system should be $u_x=v, v_{x}=-u^3+u$. But the result is the same: You are right, I made a mistake. $u=\pm 1$ are saddles and hence unstable. - - Nonetheless, I am a bit confused since, for example here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.124.6127&rep=rep1&type=pdf, it is said on page 2, that $u(t,x)=\pm 1$ are **stable** equilibria.

Comment: They refer to stability **in time**, for the full equation $u_t = u_{xx} + u - u^3$. That's why I immediately asked if you considered time or not.

Comment: That means they look for solutions $u_t=u_{xx}+u-u^3=0$? But thats what I did.

Comment: According to me, their stability means that, if the solution $u=u(t, x)$ satisfies $\|u(0, \cdot)-(\pm 1)\|<\epsilon$ (with respect to some norm), then it also satisfies $\|u(t, \cdot)- (\pm 1)\|<C\epsilon$ at all times. It is different from the stability in space for constant-in-time solutions.

Comment: Or maybe they mean the equation $u_t=u-u^3$ (as you asked in your first comment)? This has equilibria $u=0,\pm 1$ and the linearization in $u_0$ is $u_t=(-3u_0^2+1)u$ and for $u_0=\pm 1$ we have eigenvalue -2  (i.e. stability) while for $u_0=0$, the eigenvalue is 1 (i.e. instability).